# how does maven affect a java web application?

Tags: java, netbeans, maven, glassfish

I am beginning a new Java web application using Netbeans, and I would like to use Maven.  McAfee is installed on my box (here at work), which is preventing me from turning off the read-only attribute in my documents folder (where my web application project is stored).  I can run a traditional web application project, and get the 'hello world' screen on my browser.  However, if I try to run a new Maven project, I get an 'access is denied' in the console output screen.  Why is this happening, and is there a workaround?  Here's the console output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building mavenproject1 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

[dependency:copy]

[resources:resources]
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\mavenproject1\src\main\resources

[compiler:compile]
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

[resources:testResources]
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\mavenproject1\src\test\resources

[compiler:testCompile]
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

[surefire:test]
No tests to run.
Surefire report directory: C:\mavenproject1\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0


[war:war]
Packaging webapp
Assembling webapp [mavenproject1] in [C:\mavenproject1\target        
\mavenproject1-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Processing war project
Copying webapp resources [C:\mavenproject1\src\main\webapp]
Webapp assembled in [25 msecs]
Building war: C:\mavenproject1\target\mavenproject1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2.090s
Finished at: Thu Jan 12 08:48:22 EST 2012
Final Memory: 7M/17M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Access is denied.
```

Comment: As a start, provide us with the part of your pom file where you think it might be going wrong and the full stack trace of the problem, otherwise we can't help much.

Comment: Wow, your job is really paranoid if they make your personal Documents folder read-only. Kind of defeats the purpose of having one in the first place!

Comment: @Perception - it's not entirely intentional.  I just got a new fancy machine and I got the typically install package that isn't really moded for developers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely due to not being able to write to the Maven repository. You can overwrite the location of this repository via the Preferences page. Point the location to a writable directory on your computer:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to change Maven reposotory default path. Maven stores downloaded artifacts in user home. Change the folder in Netbeans settings (look for maven tab).

Answer (score 1):

maven is an external program to your web application and your **antivirus** should give it permission to read the files and generate some other files (target folder with compiled classes) in the same directories.

Answer (score 1):

Your firewall is preventing the NetBeans to connect it to Maven Repository. Maven is a tool which provides the necessary jars to your project so that you don't have to add them manually.

However you still need to specify all the needed jars (along with their versions and other information) to a project configuration file (in POM.xml) . Than at build time the maven accesses the configuration and downloads the jars from maven repository.

[Maven Repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)

[The Complete Reference to Maven](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/)

Answer (score 0):

Maven will try to create various files when you build a pproject, usually in a folder called "target".  It will also download dependencies to your home directory (usually in a subfolder ".m2/repository"),

I'm not sure how you plan to make a webapp on a read-only filesystem.